# Как запустить несколько потоков чтения/записи одновременно?

Tags: node.js, потоки-данных

Делаю загрузку файлов на сервер. Хочу использовать потоки.

Я попытался кое-что сделать:

```js
//FileSystem handler library
var log = require("core/lib/log")(module);
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');

var fsh = function (files) {

    var $this = this;

    this.moveUploadedFiles = function(dest,cb){
        if(!Object.keys(files).length){
            log.info('fsh.moveUploadedFiles-> files object is empty');
            return cb({state:0}); //files not found
        }

        async.waterfall ([
            function (cb) {
                $this.createFolder(dest,function(){
                    cb(null);
                });
            }
        ], function () {
            var infile = [];
            var outfile = [];
            var uploadSize = [];
            for (var i in files) {
                var path = dest + '/' + files[i].originalFilename;
                infile[i] = fs.createReadStream(files[i].path);
                outfile[i] = fs.createWriteStream(path);
                infile[i].on('data',function(data) {
                    if(!uploadSize[i]){
                        uploadSize[i] = 0;
                    }
                    uploadSize[i] += data.length/1024;
                    console.log(files[i].originalFilename + ': '+(files[i].size/1024) + '/'+uploadSize[i]+' Kb');
                    outfile[i].write(data);
                });
                infile[i].on('close', function() {
                    outfile[i].close();
                });
                infile[i].pipe(outfile[i]);
            }
        });

        return cb({state:1});  //upload success
    };

    this.createFolder = function(dir,cb){
        fs.exists(dir, function (exists) {
            if(exists){
                log.info('fsh.createFolder-> Dir exist: %s',dir);
                return cb();
            }else{
                fs.mkdir(dir,777,function(){
                    log.info('fsh.createFolder-> %s',dir);
                    return cb();
                });
            }
        });
    };


};

module.exports = fsh;
```

но как-то неправильно работает, несколько файлов за раз не пишет, работает только с одним. Я выбрал два разных файла, в консоли вижу следующее:

```js
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/64 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/128 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/192 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/256 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/320 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/384 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/448 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/512 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/576 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/640 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/704 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/768 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/832 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/896 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/960 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1024 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1088 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1152 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1216 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1280 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1344 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1408 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1472 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1536 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1600 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1664 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1728 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1792 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1856 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1920 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/1984 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2048 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2112 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2176 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2240 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2304 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2368 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2432 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2496 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2560 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2624 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2688 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2752 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2816 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2880 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/2944 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3008 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3072 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3136 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3200 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3264 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3328 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3392 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3456 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3520 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3584 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3597.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3661.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3725.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3789.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3853.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3917.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/3981.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/4045.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/4109.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/4173.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/4237.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/4301.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/4365.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/4429.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/4493.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/4557.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/4621.8701171875 Kb
Hawaii-Big-Island-TF.jpg: 1323.076171875/4664.9462890625 Kb
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может быть проще на клиенте считать

Comment: нет, только такой способ как описано в топике, уже близок к цели (обновил вопрос)

Comment: Весь код, относящийся к вопросу, должен быть _в самом вопросе_. Ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для начала оберните все, что в цикле `for` в функцию, иначе вы из-за замыкания обращаетесь всегда к последнему значению в массиве.
т.е. внутри `for` оставьте:

```js
(function(i) {
  var path = dest + '/' + files[i].originalFilename;
  infile[i] = fs.createReadStream(files[i].path);
  outfile[i] = fs.createWriteStream(path);
  infile[i].on('data', function(data) {
    if (!uploadSize[i]) {
      uploadSize[i] = 0;
    }
    uploadSize[i] += data.length / 1024;
    console.log(files[i].originalFilename + ': ' + (files[i].size / 1024) + '/' + uploadSize[i] + ' Kb');
  });
  infile[i].pipe(outfile[i]);
})(i);
```

Минимально работающий пример:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var r = fs.createReadStream('/some/readable/file');
var w = fs.createWriteStream('/dest/file');
var size = 0;
r.on('data', function(data) {
  size += data.length;
  console.log(size);
});

r.pipe(w);
```

Comment: Я так понимаю тут проблема в pipe или on('data'), если убрать on('data') то все работает. Но мне нужно выводить прогресс загрузки

Comment: не нужно в outfile руками дописывать, т.к. уже есть `.pipe`.

Comment: 2. У WritableStream нет метода `.close()`, есть метод `.end()`.

3. Метод `.end()` тоже не нужно использовать, т.к. по умолчанию, `.pipe()` по закрытию потока чтения, сам вызывает `.end()` у потока записи.
Все это описано в документации node.js

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы! Я не до конца понимал как работает pipe(). Спасибо вам!